# How to use composite query in firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a question about `firestore` query.
I'm working `react native` project with `firestore`
I made `index` to retrieve data which has been voted in a week.
So, my code is like below.

```js
db.getData
    .where('updatedAt' '<=' now - week)
    .orderBy('count', 'desc')
```

I know it's not allowed in firestore.
Any idea of this?

If I need to restructure DB, then please show me how it looks.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from ordering the results on the client any way you want.

Comment: I know actually now it’s working like that. However data list would be bigger than now, then this working would be slow

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of `updatedAt` data. Is is a `date` object or a `number` or `string` timestamp? I prefer to store updates with plain `Date.now()` timestamps (as `number` type). So, if `updatedAt` is a `number` it's a simple comparison. Tip, ...just name it `updated` rather than `updatedAt`, so you have `created` and `updated` fields.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It’s timestamp. I have to retrieve data which has updated in a week also, order data as descended at the same time. However, I have no idea how to do this work at the same time when I query... What am I missing here? :(